# How can I make the Swype keyboard type "I" when I press "i", now it types "ki"?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, 2.1-eclair, keyboard, 2.1-eclair, swype

I am using the Swype keyboard preloaded on my at&t Captivate (Samsung Galaxy S) phone and I like it a lot. My only problem is that when I try to write `I` I'm used to just pressing `i` and letting the phone capitalize it. However Swype routinely writes `ki` when I am trying to write `I`.

I am wondering if anyone else has this problem and if they know how to fix it?

Also, is there a way for me to remove `ki` from Swype's internal dictionary so it'll never attempt to write it? It might be useful to modify that dictionary for other reasons too, so I can add personal names, local street names, etc.

Is there an auto text replacement app that I can use to always change `ki` to `I`?

Thanks!

Comment: I've only ever typed i as a single lowercase word and it's always capitalised it for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually I had the same problem as you, and I searched the help dictionary. You have to swype from "I" down to the spacebar in order for it to auto-cap. It's not as easy to find or widely known. Also as a heads-up you can do this with "a" too. The brilliant thing about it is that you only have to be close to the "I" and "a" in order for it to space/cap.

Comment: ...or fling up above the top row. This is mentioned in the tutorial isn't it?

Answer (score 12):

Open up the memo application (or anywhere that you can enter text), enter the "ki" that's giving you problems, highlight it and hit the Swype key on the lower left; it will prompt you to delete the word.

In general it will remember new words that you enter; you may have to type them out letter-by-letter first.

Comment: I'm not getting that prompt to delete the word when I hit the Skype key. What's it look like? How do I get it?

Comment: @adam: I couldn't reproduce the exact behavior that your were seeing, but it seems 'ki' is a built-in word (it's the TLD for [Kiribati](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiribati)).  I think you'll have to spell out the 'I' by hand for a while until Swype's prediction algorithm chooses it over 'ki'.

Comment: Oh so the technique you are describing only works for user added words? That's still useful just not in this case. Is there no way to delete words from Swype's internal dictionary? Shame I use the word `I` more often than I type out URIs to I-Kiribati websites. Thanks!

Comment: @adam: the "official" way to enter 'I' is to sweep from the 'i' key to the space key.  Have you tried that?  Eventually your phone should learn that you refer to yourself more than to island nations in the Pacific. :)

Answer (score 7):

Capitalizing in Swype is pretty easy.  If I wanted to swype `Joe` I would hit the `j` and then swype to a point above the keyboard on the screen, then back down to `o` and `e`.  If I wanted to do `JOE`, I would swype from `j` to a point above the keyboard, then do a little loop while still above the keyboard, then swype to `o` and `e`.

So, in order to get a capital `I`, hit the letter `i` and the sweep up above the keyboard and then let go.

Comment: Yeah I'd rather not have to do that. I never type `i` as a single lowercase word. It should auto-capitalize without me having to remember to sweep my finger up.